# Not able to correctly read the file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a test.csv file which looks as below

```
LOC,IP,D1,D2
abc1,10.13|10.12|10.13|10.14|10.15|10.16,10.11.1.1,11.1.1.23
abc2,12.11|10.15|10.116|10.127|10.110,11.110.8.25,11.11.5.3
abc3,13.21|13.2,10.1.4.50,10.2.7.3
```

I want to calculate Ipaddress on the target server and then check if the `ipaddress` matches the value in `test.csv` file. If it matches then I want to call `check_func` and `pass values of D1 and D2` to that function.

So far, I am able to calculate `ipaddress` using the following command

```
host=`uname -n'`
ip_addr=`host $host | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

Now, I want to do something like below:

```
case $ip_addr in
      10.11|10.12|10.13|10.14|10.15|10.16)
             check_func "10.11.1.1" "11.1.1.23"
```

I have written the following script but it is not giving correct result. I am always getting the output `Unknown.`

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
IFS_backup=$IFS
IFS=,
while read -r column1 column2 column3 column4 ; do
   shopt -s extglob
   case "$ip_addr" in
      @($column2)) check_func "$column3" "$column4" ;;
      *) echo Unknown. ;;
   esac
done < file.csv
```

Comment: Why is this tagged for sed? I don't see any sed here.

Comment: What do you see from `echo $column2`?

Comment: I am getting all values from `$column2`  `10.11|10.12|10.13|10.14|10.15|10.16`  `12.1|10.15|10.116|10.127|10.110`  `13.2|13.2`

Comment: And the contents of `$ip_addr`?

Comment: I think i got the problem here. `ip_addr` will always have the 4 octets. So i need to change the logic to take 3 octets from the ip address and match it in the file and if there is nothing then take 2 octets from the ip address and match it in the file

Answer (score 1):

Glob matches need to be exact. A prefix or substring match won't trigger the case clause.

So you probably want

```
@($column2)*) check_func "$column3" "$column4" ;;
```

which effectively accepts a prefix match of any of the alternatives.

By the way, a cleaner way to set `IFS` for just the `read` statement is

```
while IFS=, read -r column1 column2 column3 column4 ; do
```

That just sets `IFS` for the environment of the `read` command, so you don't need to worry about it affecting the rest of the script.

Comment: It seems to be working. But, I am also getting `Unknown` in the output 3 times

Comment: @mealhour: The case statement is executed once for every line in the CSV file. Three of the lines don't match, so you get the `Unknown` message. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: my expectation is to get `Unknown` only if there not even a single match. If there is a match then there should not be any `Unknown`

Comment: @mealhour: then you will have to handle csv lines which don't match in some other way than printing an error message. Bash is doing exactly what you asked it to do.

Comment: thanks...can you please suggest how to update the `case statement` in my situation?

Comment: @mealhour: One simple solution would be to return from the script after you find a match, and only print the error message if the loop terminates without returning. (You can use the `exit` command to return from the script.)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

```
host=$(uname -n)
awk -F, -v ip_addr="$(host "$host")" '
    BEGIN { sub(/.*[[:space:]]/,"",ip_addr) }
    { gsub(/\./,"[.]",$2) }
    ip_addr ~ $2 { print $3, $4; f=1 }
    END { if (!f) print "Unknown" | "cat>&2" }
' file.csv |
xargs -n 2 check_func
```

Untested of course since you didn't provide a complete set of sample input/output we could test against but hopefully it's close enough for you to fix if it's not exactly right.